# Check if an executable is present and install if not

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I googled and found this post: [Link to the post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-a-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not)
From there i found a command that controlls if the following program/tool is installed. So i decided to put it into use.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

programs=$(bc nmap coreutils xmlstarlet)
if [ $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' "$programs" 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed") -eq 0 ];
then
apt-get update | apt-get install "$programs" -y;
fi
```

Am i doing this correctly? or is there something wrong in this?

I simply need a way that i put `program/tool name` to `programs variable` and then it would run it in my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use the `command -v` to check if it is installed, the return code on the if condition would help you to install if its *not* already installed

```
apt-get update
programs=(bc nmap coreutils xmlstarlet)

for program in "${programs[@]}"; do
    if ! command -v "$program" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        apt-get install "$program" -y
    fi
done
```

The option `command -v` is POSIX compliant. You can run `apt-get update` just once and not for every iteration of the loop. Also you've defined `programs` as a variable which should have been an array for iteration.

Comment: would i be able to move the `apt-get update` to `apt-get update ; apt-get install "$program" -y` ? so it would only do the update part also if something is missing?

Comment: @TheSebM8: You can but you _don't_ want to do that. You don't need to update repo data for every iteration

Comment: Rodger that. Will not change it then and will keep it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to exit from the script if some command is missing:

```
require() {
  local command not_found

  for command; do
    if ! command -v -- "${command}" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      printf 'ERROR: Command not found: %s\n' "${command}" >&2
      ((not_found++))
    fi
  done

  if ((not_found > 0)); then
    printf 'ERROR: Missing commands: %d\n' "${not_found}"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

But if you also want to install the missing commands:

```
install_command_if_not_found() {
  local command commands not_found

  for command; do
    if ! command -v -- "${command}" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      commands+=("${command}")
      ((not_found++))
    fi
  done

  if ((not_found > 0)); then
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y -- "${commands[@]}"
  fi
}
```

Example:

```
$ require cat foo curl bar mpv baz zenity
ERROR: Command not found: foo
ERROR: Command not found: bar
ERROR: Command not found: baz
ERROR: Missing commands: 3
```

---

**Notes:**

1. The code above uses Bash-specific syntax.
2. Take into account that there are cases where the name of a command and the name of its package are different, so the second function won't work in those cases.